# Sqlite execute with *args in python

Tags: python, sqlite

I'm currently trying to catch possible errors and bundle the calls within 1 function.
My problem is, that I can't use the *args parameter in the execute function of my cursor.

```
def execute_query(self, query, *args, **kwargs):
    """
    execute the query in the database with synchronized blocks

    :param query:
    :return:
    """
    result = kwargs.pop("result", None)
    try:
        self.lock.acquire(True)
        if args:
            print "args", args
            self.cursor.execute(query, args)
        else:
            self.cursor.execute(query)
        if result:
            return self.cursor.fetchall()
    except sqlite3.ProgrammingError as err:
        self.logger.warn("An error occured: {0:s}".format(err))
    finally:
        self.lock.release()
```

I call the function like this:

```
    self.execute_query(u"DELETE FROM DownloadQueue WHERE path=? AND url=?", path, url, result=False)
```

In the print I get following result:

```
args (u'page_001.jpg', u'http://www.google.de')
```

followed by following error:

```
2015-10-12 01:47:17,543 [MainThread] [WARNI]  An error occured: Incorrect number of bindings supplied. The current statement uses 2, and there are 0 supplied.
```

But if I use this printed argument directly in the console it works fine:

```
>>> cursor.execute(u"DELETE FROM DownloadQueue WHERE path=? AND url=?", (u'page_001.jpg', u'http://www.google.de'))
```

Why exactly do I receive this error, even though the parameters should be completely the same? And how can I prevent this?

Edit:
The code works fine, somehow my IDE cached old code, else I can't explain how this function call got used, but after restarting my IDE the code worked fine...

kind regards

Comment: My only guess is `self.cursor.execute` is not the same thing as `cursor.execute` on the console or it's in some unusual state. Check this with `pdb` and also what's happening in the call.

Comment: (random guess) is the indentation okay?

Comment: I'm really sorry, the args parameter actually works completely fine, after restarting my IDE it worked without any problems, not even sure how this was cached in pycharm...